# How does command response work in a BLE device?

Tags: xamarin.android, bluetooth-lowenergy, android-ble, bluetooth-lowenergy-4.2

I am able to connect to a BLE device. Then into the command services Writable Characteristics, I am writing a command. OnCharacteristicsWrite returns the GattStatus as Success as well. Where can I obtain the response to the command?

Comment: In Bluetooth Low energy there are notifications, read and write operations. Check with the BLE device with which you connect, to know what operations it support. Usually you receive data from BLE peripheral devices in the form of notifications.

Comment: @Ravi So when we write commands into the Write Characteristic of a Service, the Read Characteristic should already have the notification enabled so that we get the response data there?

Comment: Reading characteristic and receiving notifications are the only ways to receive data from BLE devices. Notifications are a way that BLE devices can notify data to MobileApp. If your BLE device supports notifications, enable them before you write characteristics. You can use nRFConnect android app for reference to see what are all your BLE device supports.